# Coding a jQuery rolodex-style clock flip animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation

I'm struggling to build a simple animation based on those old clocks with flip-down numbers. I added an image below copied from a freebie PSD found on Premium Pixels:

[image: flip-clock PSD]

The biggest problem I'm running into is building a "flipping" animation using jQuery **all in HTML/CSS/JavaScript**. The only tutorial I've found is [from this net tuts+ article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/learn-how-to-create-a-retro-animated-flip-down-clock/) which actually uses images. It splits the top and bottom half of the clock into two different image sets and replaces them for each second that passes by...

This method isn't realistic in a website since it provides no actual context for readers. I'd prefer to have the numbers hard coded into HTML and perform the flipping animation solely through jQuery - preferably no images except background ticker boxes. Or to put it another way the **numbers** are coded into HTML but the clock itself is a series of rolodex-style bg images.

I hope I've explained this well enough.. I've been struggling on this for a few days and I honestly have no idea how to approach this script. Maybe by splitting the top and bottom halves into different divs, then change the internal numbers for each second that passes? I'm fairly well-off in jQuery but I am weak on animations.

Thanks in advance for any support!

Comment: Try the [jQuery image rotate](http://webmuch.com/image-flip-using-jquery/) technique.

Comment: Maybe this could be a start..

http://dabblet.com/gist/2360985

Comment: @OscarBroman Nice, but looks like it is an experimental feature and not supported in most versions.

Comment: Most up-to-date browsers support it, except for IE (as usual).

Comment: @OscarBroman hey wow man, did you code that all with CSS3/HTML5? no jquery at all? i suppose something like that could work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would attempt to do something where the text is duplicated for the top and bottom. Then using images and css to only display each half appropriately.

The next step would be creating the illusion that the text is flipping with the image. I am not sure how you want to do that. I think it is a matter of sizing and speed. The sizing of the text in relation to the image and the speed at which it flips from the top of bottom.

The final part of the animation is having the top half ready with the next number and the bottom half queue up on completion.

I don't have any actual code that will help, but I hope this concept is something that will work out.